# React Native - How to set properties on ActivityIndicatorIOS from grand-child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to use a "global" ActivityIndicatorIOS in the top-level of my React Native app (index.ios.js) so I can control it through out the app when I need to turn it on and off.

**App structure:**

```
index.ios.js    <- ActivityIndicatorIOS here
 |
tabbar.ios.js
 |
tab1.js     <- Need to reference it from here
tab2.js                    "
tab3.js                    "
```

I'd really like to know the best way to do this, rather than reusing the component on each view in the app, have it sit over the "top level" NavigatorIOS and be able to turn it on and off.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very similar to the example here with a "global" modal screen: https://rnplay.org/apps/V6vU6g

This article explains how this can be done: http://browniefed.com/blog/2015/10/18/react-native-easy-overlay-modal-with-navigator/

Basically, in your case, you would have an ActivityIndicatorIOS in said modal, and you would pass down to your tab components a function that sets the state in your index.ios.js on whether it's visible or not. You can execute this function wherever you want later on down the chain. When this state changes, your ActivityIndicator can be set to render over the Navigator (if you choose).