# How to make loader center on the View

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

On one View displaying the page in that page I need to display the loader  but the loader need to display it on center.

```
var LoaderPositionCenter = React.createClass({
    render:function(){
       return(<View  style=   {{backgroundColor:'blue',flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}>
                <View>
                   <Text>one</Text>
                   <Text>one</Text>
                   <Text>one</Text>
                   <Text>one</Text>
                   <Text>one</Text>
                   <Text>one</Text>
                   <Text>one</Text>
                   <Text>one</Text>
              </View>
    <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <Text style={{textAlign:'center',color:'yellow'}}>
           textsds dsdsdsd
        </Text>
    </View>       
   </View>)
    }
})
```

On First View content i need to show the loader as center how can make it using flexbox

//New one

```
var Example = React.createClass({
        getInitialState:function(){
            return {status:"button"}
        },
      click:function(){
          this.setState({status:"buttonText"});
      },
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            position:'relative',
          }}>
              <View style={{//content view
                 position:'absolute',
                 top:0,
                 left:0,
                 right:0,
                 bottom:0,
              }}>
                  <ScrollView>
                     {
                     <TouchableHighlight 
                         underlayColor="#ffa456" 
                         onPress={this.click}
                      >
                        <Text>{this.state.status}</Text>
                      </TouchableHighlight>
                      }
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                       <Text>one</Text>
                       <Text>one</Text>
                       <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                      <Text>one</Text>
                  </ScrollView>
              </View>
              <View style={{
                    flex:1,
                    alignItems:'center',
                    justifyContent:'center'
              }}>
                 <Image source={{uri:icons.loader}}
                    style=  {styles.loader}/>
               </View>
          </View>
        );
      }
    });
```

How to disable the content view that means position:'absolute' view using flexbox or other

Comment: I thought I'd try to work this out for you, but it's late and I'm getting tired. However, I think the answer can be found here https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-modal if you dig into it. There's an <Overlay> component that could be really useful as well. Good luck!

Comment: And see this too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459609/react-native-how-to-set-properties-on-activityindicatorios-from-grand-child-co

Comment: Thank you Chris Geirman .Actually i want to work this loader make center for both android and ios but react-native-modal is works for ios only.

Comment: understood, I'm not suggesting you use them as much as I'm suggesting you understand how they work since you are trying to solve a similar problem

Comment: Yes i understood Chris Geirman.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the outer container to have a style property of:

```
flex: 1,
alignItems: 'center', 
justifyContent: 'center'
```

I've set up a full project [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/Lq4G9w), and pasted the entire code below:

https://rnplay.org/apps/Lq4G9w

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ActivityIndicatorIOS
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        animating: true
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <ActivityIndicatorIOS animating={this.state.animating} style={[{height: 80}]} size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }

});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ddd'
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Thank you Nader Dabit. It's working for IOS  but how can i achieve the same effect for android also  because in my project i am using the same code for both Android and IOS

Comment: I guess I didn't understand what you were trying to accomplish. I thought you were trying to create an overlay on top of content with a spinner centered. Glad Nader had our back :). The ActivityIndicatorIOS is just for iOS, but here's one ([FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-spinner](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-spinner))that claims to be cross-platform. There are plenty of others too https://react.parts/native?search=spinner

Comment: Exactly i want to create an overlay on  top of content with a spinner centered .Now i achieve this with flexbox but i have a problem the overlay content should be disabled when the spinner is loaded. I updated the code above with working one

Comment: I worked with react-native-gifted-spinner but while adding the content the loader comes down but in my scenario always loader should be center and while loader is running user unable to perform the operations on content