# How to disable the View using react-native flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native

In my scenario i want to disable the View(example:while loader is running the overlay content that means the loader behind View content need to be disable ).
How to achieve this using flexbox or anything

Comment: whatever the loader you used it will automatically apply the overlay which loader you used for it

Comment: I am using static loader image.Actually my problem is please follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468678/how-to-make-loader-center-on-the-view